# Native scrollbar gets scaled while zooming in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript

When applying zoom to the overflowing container, scrollbar also gets scaled in IE and Firefox. please refer the below image.
[when zoomed to 400%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGUa5.png)

please refer the below css.

```
#innerdiv{
width: 163px;
height:50px;
zoom: 400%;
overflow:auto;
position:relative;
}
#parentdiv{
width: 650px;
height:200px;
}
```

When zooming the overflowing content, facing the above issue in IE and firefox.

I tried to set the overflow property to the parent div instead of zoom div[innerdiv].

Though i am getting the scrollbars without its size change on zooming, some part of the innerdiv is not completely inherited to the parent div, while scrolling. please refer the below image.
[position not inherited properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkuKn.png)

please check this sample
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWBBTM88SZE9

How the position of inner div has be maintained to parent div? please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) is non-standard, use `transform` instead.

Comment: Tried transform property too. But not working